# Instantiating multiple objects in one frame or one object per frame?

Tags: performance, loops, unity-game-engine, random

The idea is simple 'instantiating a map' in Awake with random values.

But the Question is:
Should i instantiate the whole map in one frame (using Loop)?
or better to instantiate each object per frame?

Because i don't want to ruin player's ram by instantiating 300 gameobjects in less than a second.

Comment: If it happens during app start or loading a scene I would do it all together. If they do not depend on each other you might want to give it a shot spreading it over multiple frames **but** think about what is worse: 1 hanging frame for a larger moment once or maybe 300 hanging frames for shorter moments but still stuttering due to Instantiating one object each frame (which would take about 5 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever make things that depends on frames, never!!
There are some exceptions when this can be good but most of the time its not.

Good case:
- Incremental garbage collection (still has drawbacks)

Bad case:
- Your case, loading a map should be at the beginning

Why i should not make my game frame dependent?

- Because, PCs have different computational speed, a good example was Harry Potter II, the game was developed for machines capable of 30 frames per seconds, modern machines can run that game extremely fast thus the game is basically sped up, you need to manually throttle the CPU to make the game playable.
- Another example is unitys delta time, the reason you use it when moving objects over multiple frames because it takes into account the last frames computation speed

Also 300 objects is nothing when loading a game, also from a player point of view:

What is better 10 seconds loading, or 30 seconds 15 fps then normal speed
(above example is exaggerated tho)

Comment: Instantiating objects at frame update is not frame dependent though. No matter what the FPS, it still reliably instantiates with the same logic, it just takes more time.

Comment: I partly agree this is not a too well explained answer reading it again. Feel free to edit it!

Answer (score 2):

Whether you instantiate all `gameobjects` in one frame or not, they will always end up in the RAM the same way. The only way to "ruin" someone's ram would be to instantiate so many `gameobjects` til there is no memory left. Considering that a typical `prefab` in unity is only a few kb in size and a typical RAM nowadays is a few GB in size , that would take roughly a million gameobjects.

Answer (score 0):

When loading a map you can do it asynchronously at the start of entering the scene. This way you can put a loadingscreen during the loading time. This is a good way to do it if you are making a single player game. If it's a multiplayer game you need to sync it on the server for every other player aswell. The method for loading a scene async is `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync()`.

If you're trying to instantiate objects during runtime because you want to randomize certain objects I would recommend loading every object that doesn't need randomizing by entering the scene (so dropping them in the scene).

This is how I interpreted your question tell me if I am wrong.